# Hex to ascii in c using visual studio

Tags: c, visual-studio, ascii

I'm facing some issues while I use `toascii()` it converts any int to ascii, but not int < 10, it returens `\x1` or `\x2` and so but not the ascii symbol which it should represent. so, any help please.

My code be like:

```
char* PostUnpack()
{
    char* InStr = "04214FABF666DCE7";
    int Len = strlen(InStr);
    int Count, OutCount = 0;
    int IntToHex;
    char HexToChr[3] = "";
    char TempCnv;
    char RetStr[20] = "" ;

    for(Count = 0; Count < Len; Count++)
    {
        strncpy(HexToChr,&InStr[Count],2);
        IntToHex = (int) strtol(HexToChr, NULL, 16);
        TempCnv = IntToHex;
        toascii(TempCnv);
        RetStr[OutCount] = TempCnv;
        strncpy(HexToChr, "", strlen(HexToChr));
        Count++;
        OutCount++;
    }
    return RetStr;
```

actually in debug it be like:

```
\x4!O«öfÜç
```

while it should be :

```
!O«öfÜç
```

because I don't want to print the out put, but I use the return value to be used by some encryption method, and now when I pass this incorrect return value it make an incorrect encryption.

Comment: What is the result you expect?

Comment: Most of those don't even have a commonly used symbol. Is it \0, \b and \t you want?

Comment: Please show code and output so we can help you.

Comment: In the ASCII table, indices below 32 are known as "non-printable characters". What exactly do you expect a non-printable character to look like?

Comment: @Lundin actually I Tried to paste the character which I expected to appear here, but it doesn't work

Comment: What is your desired goal? Do you want do convert a number into a string? Calling `toascii` does not change the parameter anyway.

Comment: @Gerhardh Well, I'm trying to convert a hex to ascii

Comment: What do you mean with "ascii"?

Comment: @Gerhardh ascii encoding charterer dude!!

Comment: You are failing to add a NUL on the end of HexToChr after strncpy.

Comment: @Zainab - Did anything anyone here said help you in any way?

Comment: note that returning retstr is illegal, no matter what this function does you will get garbage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already pointed out, one of the issues may be that `toascii()`, although working as designed, is not be producing it's converted value in the way you expect.  You must *use the return value of the function to get the converted value*.  For example, as you have called it:

```
    toascii(TempCnv);//the converted value is returned, and you are not capturing it.
^^^^
```

use either a direct assignment statement to capture the value like this:

```
char c = toascii(0x51); //example value should produce ASCII character 3
```

Or you can use the string function *[sprintf()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_sprintf.htm)* to place the converted value into a variable:

```
char c = 0;
sprintf(c, "%c", toascii(0x51));
```

Also, the range of printable ASCII characters is 0x20 - 0x7E.  There is a paper that discusses the problems that are encountered when attempting to work with non-printable characters *[here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0ahUKEwjXmr6ysdbTAhXHjFQKHXrgBRAQFggpMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.lexjansen.com%2Fpharmasug%2F2010%2FCC%2FCC13.pdf&usg=AFQjCNEfDHLmCwfoqrDVj0WzzYxbSfDZvA&sig2=orgNy1q9FgMMkBL_g2WgfQ&cad=rja)*

Answer (score 0):

heres one that works

```
char * conv(char * str)
{
    int l = strlen(str);
    char buff[3];
    buff[2] = 0;
    int oidx = 0;
    char *out = malloc(l/2 + 1);
        int i;
    for( i = 0; i < l; )
    {
        buff[0]= str[i++];
        buff[1] = str[i++];
        long x = strtol(buff, 0,16);
        out[oidx++] = x;

    }
    out[oidx] = 0;
    return strdup(out);
}   
int main(void) {

   char* InStr = "04214FABF666DCE7";
     char* ans = conv(InStr);
      free(ans);
}
```

does not deal with odd length input. Note the allocation of return buffer and freeing by caller. And  no check of malloc

Answer (score -1):

It seems the point of `toascii()` is to limit a value to using at most 7 bits, i.e. `toascii(x)` is equivalent to `x &= 127`. This might not be what you expect.

See [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf55c429.aspx) for details.

Comment: As he doesn't use the return value of `toascii` at all, that doesn't really matter. ;)